# Error al imprimir string con carácter especial, muestra símbolo raro

Tags: python

Estoy utilizando visual studio code y estoy con la codificación utf-8.

Al hacer:

```py
print("¿Cuantos años tienes?")
```

El resultado es:

```
�Cuantos años tienes?
```

Comment: Tu problema capaces de mucho contexto, pues si yo ejecuto esto en mi pc o cualquier servidor en la nube saldrá bien. Para poder replicar tu problema o darnos una mejor idea de lo que pasa recomiendo que añades más detalles, como por ejemplo, que consola usas, cual es el encodig que usa tu script, etc.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python estás usando? ¿Qué codificación tiene el documento? (ANSI, UTF8) ¿Estás ejecutándolo directo en el IDE o en la consola del sistema? ¿Qué IDE es? ¿Qué sistema operativo tiene el equipo?